# Why is this series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (sin\frac{1}{n}-sin\frac{1}{n+1}) $$ converge?

since neither $$a_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  sin\frac{1}{x}$$ nor $$b_{n}\sum_{n=1}^\infty sin\frac{1}{x+1}$$  converge, so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}$$ should not converge either right?

Comment: Telescope the partial sums and pass to the limit.

Comment: It telescopes. Dude.

Comment: @Tmm The statement is incorrect, because that's like saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ don't converge, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 - 1$ does not converge. This rule is not present in general when it comes to sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this sum is telescoping. Observe that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} - \sin \frac{1}{n+1} \right)
= \left(\sin 1 - \sin\frac{1}{2}\right) + \left(\sin \frac{1}{2} - \sin\frac{1}{3} \right) + \cdots
$$
and the adjacent $\sin\frac{1}{n}$ cancel. Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \sin \frac{1}{n} - \sin \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sin\frac{1}{1} - \sin\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\sin(x)$. By the mean value theorem there is $a_n \in (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ such that

$\sin(\frac{1}{n})-\sin(\frac{1}{n+1})=\cos(a_n)*\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$